# Ajax not hitting controller method

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following jquery function which is sending data to a controller:

```
function bound(e) {
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("e-grid")[0]
    ele.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('e-up')) {
            var grid = document.getElementById('FlatGrid').ej2_instances[0];  //Grid Instance 
            var rowObj = grid.getRowObjectFromUID(ej.base.closest(e.target, '.e-row').getAttribute('data-uid'));
            var  data = rowObj.data;
            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            var code = data.ClientCode;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Client/ShowClient",
                data: { "ClientCode": code }, //First item has latest ID
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.length !== 0) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }

    });
}
```

And my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowClient(string ClientCode)
    {
        if (ClientCode == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        *action*
    }
```

However I am getting a 500 (Internal Server Error) error for this.  Any idea what I am missing cause my method is not being hit at all.
And I can see that var code does have the correct string value.

Comment: Remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` option

Comment: can you just try passing the code value directly like  data: JSON.stringify(code)

Comment: Can you provide more information about the 500 (Internal Server Error) ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your application on the client side?
Open up your developer tools and look at the content of the 500 error in the network tab.

Comment: Try replacing your url parameter with `'@Url.Action("ShowClient", "ControllerName")'`. Use your controller name.

Comment: Does setting Client code to null return the correct BadRequest response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove commas from the parameter name "ClientCode" and contentType and will be work

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Client/ShowClient",
            data: { ClientCode: code }, //First item has latest ID
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length !== 0) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments have provided you with a combination of suggestions that when put together will give you the desired behavior.

First, you can build the URL in teh view using `@Url.Action`

```
url: '@(Url.Action("ShowClient","Client"))',
```

Next, the object model is not being built correctly

```
data: { ClientCode: code },
```

Note the last of quotes around the key.

And finally remove the JSON content type.

Which results to portion of code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@(Url.Action("ShowClient","Client"))',
    data: { ClientCode: code },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.length !== 0) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the url to this:

```
url: "../Client/ShowClient"
```